# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'company'

Tags: python, class, oop, object

i cannot figure this out. i guess i'm wrong about how to call a object.
and objects are not called the company name, apperently.

after registered a customer, choose 2 to go to submenu to show customer list,
then write customer name to show more information about the specific customer

```
# APP REVOLUTIO SOLUTIONS - OverView ARS v1.0



class OVARS:

    def __init__(self, company, kNr, adr, tlf, sp, app, appV, date, afd, ini):

        self.company = company
        self.kNr = kNr
        self.adr = adr
        self.tlf = tlf
        self.sp = sp
        self.app = app
        self.appV = appV
        self.date = date
        self.afd = afd
        self.ini = ini


class udskriv(OVARS):

    def __init__(self):
        super(OVARS, self).__init__()


    def udskriv_kunde(self, cuna):
        print(cuna.company)
        print(cuna.kNr)
        print(cuna.adr)
        print(cuna.tlf)
        print(cuna.sp)
        print(cuna.app)
        print(cuna.appV)
        print(cuna.date)
        print(cuna.afd)
        print(cuna.ini)



######################## PROGRAM START ########################

udskrivKALD = udskriv()

print('OverView ARS v1.0')


customerList = []
i = 0

while True:

    try:
        menuChoice = int(input('''
1. apply new customer
2. show existing customers
3. exit
        \n'''))
    except ValueError:
        print('choice not accepted.\n')
        continue

    print()

    if menuChoice == 1:

        addCompanyName = input('enter company name: ')
        addKundeNr = input('enter customer ID.: ')
        addAdresse = input('enter address: ')
        addTelefon = input('enter telephone nr.: ')
        addSP = input('enter Servicepackage: ')
        addApp = input('enter app: ')
        addAppV = input('enter App version: ')
        addDate = input('enter Date: ')
        addAfd = input('enter department: ')
        addIni = input('enter Inititials: ')

        customerList.append(addCompanyName)

        print('\ncustomer registered: ' + str(addCompanyName) + '\n')

        newCustomer = addCompanyName

        newCustomer = OVARS(addCompanyName, addKundeNr, addAdresse, addTelefon, addSP, addApp, addAppV, addDate, addAfd, addIni)

        continue


    elif menuChoice == 2:

        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 1
        for i in customerList:
            print(str(k) + ': ' + customerList[j])
            j += 1
            k += 1


        subMenu2Choice = input('''
choose customer to show customer information,
or choose 0 to go back to first menu
    \n''')


        if subMenu2Choice == 0:
            continue

        elif subMenu2Choice in customerList:
            udskrivKALD.udskriv_kunde(subMenu2Choice)

        else:
            print('wrong choice')
            continue


    elif menuChoice == 3: # Exiting Program
        break


    else:
        print('choice not accepted.\n')
        continue

    #udskrivKALD.udskriv_kunde(newCustomer)


print()

# END OF PROGRAM
```

PLEASE HELP D:

MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS MORE DETAILS

Comment: `udskriv_kunde` expects an `OVARS` instance (`cuna`), but you're passing a string: `udskrivKALD.udskriv_kunde(subMenu2Choice)` (`subMenu2Choice = input(...`).

Comment: i know, and my intention is that you see a list of customers, and then write a customer name in the input, but the objects never get created with the customer name when registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick fix:

As someone already mentioned in the comment you are trying to pass in a string to a function that expects a particular object. You can use `customerList` to store all the created objects and not just the `company` attribute:

`customerList.append(newCustomer)`

For the show existing customers fix, use this snippet:

```
elif any(i.company==subMenu2Choice for i in customerList):
            for i in customerList:
                if i.company==subMenu2Choice:udskrivKALD.udskriv_kunde(i)
```

Code:

```
# APP REVOLUTIO SOLUTIONS - OverView ARS v1.0
class OVARS:
    def __init__(self, company, kNr, adr, tlf, sp, app, appV, date, afd, ini):
        self.company = company
        self.kNr = kNr
        self.adr = adr
        self.tlf = tlf
        self.sp = sp
        self.app = app
        self.appV = appV
        self.date = date
        self.afd = afd
        self.ini = ini

class udskriv(OVARS):
    def __init__(self):
        super(OVARS, self).__init__()

    def udskriv_kunde(self, cuna):
        print(cuna.company)
        print(cuna.kNr)
        print(cuna.adr)
        print(cuna.tlf)
        print(cuna.sp)
        print(cuna.app)
        print(cuna.appV)
        print(cuna.date)
        print(cuna.afd)
        print(cuna.ini)

######################## PROGRAM START ########################

udskrivKALD = udskriv()

print('OverView ARS v1.0')

customerList = []
i = 0

while True:

    try:
        menuChoice = int(input('''
1. apply new customer
2. show existing customers
3. exit
        \n'''))
    except ValueError:
        print('choice not accepted.\n')
        continue

    print()

    if menuChoice == 1:

        addCompanyName = input('enter company name: ')
        addKundeNr = input('enter customer ID.: ')
        addAdresse = input('enter address: ')
        addTelefon = input('enter telephone nr.: ')
        addSP = input('enter Servicepackage: ')
        addApp = input('enter app: ')
        addAppV = input('enter App version: ')
        addDate = input('enter Date: ')
        addAfd = input('enter department: ')
        addIni = input('enter Inititials: ')



        print('\ncustomer registered: ' + str(addCompanyName) + '\n')

        newCustomer = addCompanyName

        newCustomer = OVARS(addCompanyName, addKundeNr, addAdresse, addTelefon, addSP, addApp, addAppV, addDate, addAfd, addIni)

        customerList.append(newCustomer)

        continue


    elif menuChoice == 2:

        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 1
        for i in customerList:
            print(str(k) + ': ' + customerList[j].company)
            j += 1
            k += 1


        subMenu2Choice = input('''
choose customer to show customer information,
or choose 0 to go back to first menu
    \n''')


        if subMenu2Choice == 0:
            continue

        elif any(i.company==subMenu2Choice for i in customerList):
            for i in customerList:
                if i.company==subMenu2Choice:udskrivKALD.udskriv_kunde(i)

        else:
            print('wrong choice')
            continue


    elif menuChoice == 3: # Exiting Program
        break


    else:
        print('choice not accepted.\n')
        continue

    #udskrivKALD.udskriv_kunde(newCustomer)


print()

# END OF PROGRAM
```

Comment: It should be working. just enter the companyName string in the subMenuChoice 2.

Comment: Oh. wait, do you want to enter the id of the entry or the company name to get the info,?? My current code needs the string.